# How to fix "cannot convert"?

Tags: c++, class, struct, explicit

I got compile errors `"cannot convert.."`, `"no instance of constructor..". I can't get what I did wrong. I tried to change the way of initialization of an object but it didn't help. Want to understand this better.

- Error C2440 '': cannot convert from 'const char
  [11]' to 'Course'
- Error C2512 'LectureTitle::LectureTitle': no    appropriate default
  constructor available
- Error (active) E0289 no    instance of constructor "Course::Course"
  matches the argument list
- Error (active)   E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "Week" 
  to "LectureTitle" exists

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    struct Specialization {
        string data;
        explicit Specialization(string& new_value) {
            data = new_value;
        }
    };
    struct Course {
        string data;
        explicit Course(string& new_value) {
            data = new_value;
        }
    };
    struct Week {
        string data;
        explicit Week(string& new_value) {
            data = new_value;
        }
    };
    struct LectureTitle {
        string specialization;
        string course;
        string week;
        LectureTitle(Specialization& new_value1, Course& new_value2, Week new_value3) {
            specialization = new_value1.data;
            course = new_value2.data;
            week = new_value3.data;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        LectureTitle title (
            Specialization("C++"),
            Course("White belt"),
            Week("4th")
        );

    }
```

Comment: Give the FULL error please. It matters what X and Y are in the sentence "cannot convert X to Y".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a complete and full copy-paste of the error output, and also add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: By the way your code is using a MSVC specific non-portable extension that allows temporary variables to be bound to non-const references. Please try to avoid such things.

Comment: Sprinkle a generous dose of `const` over your parameters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude btw where is I can switch off this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> LectureTitle title (
>         Specialization("C++"),
>         Course("White belt"),
>         Week("4th")
>     );
> ```

Here you are trying to create an instance of `LectureTitle` with temporary values (*rvalues*) of `Specialization`, `Course` and `Week`. They are temporary because they are not named variables, i.e. not defined as variables before this piece of code.

All your constructors, however, take named variables references (*lvalues*). That's why you get the compiler errors. To correct these errors you can make the constructors accept const value references like so:

```
explicit Specialization(const std::string& new_value) {
    data = new_value;
}

explicit Course(const std::string& new_value) {
    data = new_value;
}

explicit Week(const std::string& new_value) {
    data = new_value;
}

LectureTitle(const Specialization& new_value1, const Course& new_value2, const Week new_value3) {
    specialization = new_value1.data;
    course = new_value2.data;
    week = new_value3.data;
}
```

Const lvalue references can bind to rvalues - i.e. extend the lifetime of a temporary; and those temporaries can be used to intialise the member variables in your constructors.